# Writing a DFS with iterative deepening without recursion

Tags: graph, stack, graph-theory, depth-first-search, iterative-deepening

So currently i have a DFS with the following pseudocode

```
procedure DFS(Graph,source):
      create a stack S
      push source onto S
      mark source
      while S is not empty:
          pop an item from S into v
          for each edge e incident on v in Graph:
              let w be the other end of e
              if w is not marked:
                 mark w
                 push w onto S
```

How do I alter this function to accept a third argument that limits the depth of the search?

Comment: It's not fully correct DFS algorithm. It visits all successors of vertex first and then goes deeper. It should go deeper first, then backtrack to visit other child nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let **Node** be a structure for each node of the graph, add a field called *level*, then process the graph as follows:

```
procedure DFS(Graph,source, depth):
  create a stack S
  source.level = 0
  push source onto S
  mark source
  while S is not empty:
      pop an item from S into v
      if v.level > depth
        continue

      for each edge e incident on v in Graph:
          let w be the other end of e
          if w is not marked:
             mark w
             w.level = v.level + 1
             push w onto S
```

Comment: Pushing every neighbor into the stack would give a BFS because you end of looking at the neighbors first before the children.

Comment: Nop. The key point here is the data structure,  if you use a queue then you get a BFS, with a stack you get a DFS.

Comment: I think there are some problem in the above solution. You cannot pop an item from S into V immediately

Comment: @ThinkRecursively I know it seems like Python or any other language, but it's pseudo code: `pop an item from S into v` can be translated into many instructions.

Comment: You pseudo-code is incorrect. You mark all `w` in the same iteration, so it __cannot__ be DFS; while @Matilda 's comment is also incorrect, he/she pointed out that your answer is probably incorrect, then a reasonable person will check one's answer. But you said "Nop. The key point here is data structure",

Comment: while DFS requires a stack, it doesn't mean that one use a stack in his code guarantee its code behave like DFS.

Answer (score 0):

1. The procedure will return `success` when an object is found.
2. When an object is found, the `S` will contain nodes in the path [root, source). (the `source` itself is not included.)

---

```
procedure DFS(Graph, source, depth):
    StackInit(S)
    if source is goal then
        return success
    markVisited(source)
    S.push(null, source)              // S is a close-list
    while S is not empty then do
        c, p := S.pop()
        r := next(c, p)               // return the next sibling of c
        if r is null then
            continue
        S.push(r, p)
        if r is marked visited then   // that already marked means it cannot be goal
            continue
        if r is goal then
            return success
        markVisited(r)
        if equal(depth(r), depth) then // here is what OP wants.
            continue
        S.push(null, r)

return fail
```