# java iterative deepening on tree without recursion

Tags: java, search, iterative-deepening

I currently have a depth first search implemented as followed:

```
protected void algorithmLogic() {
    currentNode = ((Stack<Node>) expanded).pop();
    if(atGoal()) {
        // Goal reached so stop
        return;
    }
    else {
        visited.add(currentNode);
        if(currentNode.hasChild()) {
            for(int i=currentNode.getChildren().size()-1;i>-1;i--) {
                ((Stack<Node>) expanded).push(currentNode.getChildren().get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is working on a tree on nodes.

Is it possible to edited this code in some way such that it performed iterative deepening search? Say with limit 2? I can't think of a way to track the level.

Answer (score 0):

for those interested I solved this with help from this [Writing a DFS with iterative deepening without recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493823/writing-a-dfs-with-iterative-deepening-without-recursion?rq=1)

In my implementation I used a hashmap with node keys and an integer representing the node level as the value.